# Java Array of objects' values

Tags: java, arrays, object

```
import java.awt.*;
import hsa.Console;
public class Game{
    static Console c;
    public static void Wait (int time){
        try{
            Thread.sleep (time);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e){
        }
    }
    public static class Tile{
        public int x,y,stack;
        public Tile(){
            x = 0;
            y = 0;
            stack = 0;
        }
        public Tile(int xco, int yco, int stacknum){
            x = xco;
            y = yco;
            stack = stacknum;
        }
        public void draw(Tile tile){ //To draw the tile
            if(stack>0){
                c.setColor(Color.red);
                c.fillRect(x*78+1+x,y*78+1+y,78,78); //Calculate coordinates
            }
            else{
                c.setColor(Color.blue);
                c.fillRect(x*78+1+x,y*78+1+y,78,78);
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main (String[] args){
        c = new Console ();

        for(int i=0;i<640;i+=79) c.drawLine(i,0,i,474);
        for(int i=0;i<500;i+=79) c.drawLine(0,i,632,i);
        //8x6 tiling
        Tile[][] tile = new Tile[8][6];
        for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<6;j++){
                tile[i][j] = new Tile();
                tile[i][j].x = i;
                tile[i][j].y = j; //Set x and y coordinates
                tile[i][j].stack = 5;
            }
        }
        Tile.draw(tile[0][0]);
    }
}
```

Here I have a tile of 8x6 squares using a multidimensional array. I would think that the coordinates would correspond to the correct numbers, but for some reason the coordinates seem to copy the ones created before it. Could someone tell me why this is happening and how the code should be corrected? Btw I started java so I'm not completely used to object oriented programming :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your co-ordinates are declared as static:

```
public static int x,y,stack;
```

Fields that have the `static` modifier in their declaration are called `static` fields or class variables. They are associated with the `class`, rather than with any object. Every instance of the class shares a static class variable, which is in one fixed location in memory.

You should however remove the `static` modifier to have specific value for each object of `Tile`

**Edit:**
From your below comment and for your better understanding, to work with `draw()` function:

**Approach 1**: If we wish to have draw function to be `static`:

```
public static void draw(Tile tile){ //To draw the tile
            if(stack>0){
                c.setColor(Color.red);
                c.fillRect(tile.x*78+1 + tile.x, tile.y*78+1+tile.y, 78, 78); 
                   //Calculate coordinates
            }
            else{
                c.setColor(Color.blue);
                c.fillRect(tile.x*78+1 + tile.x, tile.y*78+1+tile.y, 78, 78); 
            }
        }
```

You can call this function by `Tile.draw(tile)`; where `tile` is an instance of `Tile`

**Approach 2:** If `draw(Title tile)` function is non static: you don't need to pass the `tile` instance at all:

```
public  void draw(){ //To draw the tile
            if(stack>0){
                c.setColor(Color.red);
                c.fillRect(tile.x*78+1 + tile.x, tile.y*78+1+tile.y, 78, 78); 
                   //Calculate coordinates
            }
            else{
                c.setColor(Color.blue);
                c.fillRect(tile.x*78+1 + tile.x, tile.y*78+1+tile.y, 78, 78); 
            }
        }
```

Then create an instance `Tile title = new Title()` and call `title.draw()`

Comment: However, if I remove the "static" to make it "public int x,y,stack", it says the variables in the draw function "can't be access in this static context".

Comment: If I remove all the "static" from the class Tile (class Tile, draw function), "new Tile()", "Tile.draw" seem to give an error

Comment: yes beacuse your draw function itself is static and you can't access non static variable from static context. remove the `static` modifier from draw function too

Comment: Now I get `Tile.draw` as an error, saying "The method "draw" is not static, and cannot be accessed in this static context.".

Comment: as i have said in the a static member is accessible by class name `Class.staticFunction()` but non-static member is accessible by the instance hence non-static function can not be called by `Class.nonStaticFunction()`

Comment: How should it be called then?

Comment: create an instance of `Tile`, let us assume it is `t` then call `t.draw()`

Comment: Then I get "No applicable overload for the method..." :/ What else needs to change?

Comment: I have updated the answer for you. But it seems you don't have minimal understanding how class construction and method calling works. you need to study more

Answer (score 0):

You've marked x, y, z as static so all instances of your class use the same ones, just remove the static keyword